# Move folder cross disks without security descriptor change

Tags: windows, file

I want to move a folder from one drive (e.g. C) to another (say D) without its security descriptor changed. SHFileOperation can move the folder, but new folder on D always inherit the permission from the parent folder. Not to impact other subfolders under the same parent folder, I cannot change the parent folder to stop propogating its permissions to its children.

I have used SetSecurityDescriptorControl with SE_DACL_PROTECTED to disable inherit when creating the folder on C. It seems not to work when move folder cross volumn. I also tried to set security info for the new folder on D, by removing old ACEs. However, those inherited ACEs cannot be removed.

There is a registry ForceCopyAclwithFile (http://thedailyreviewer.com/server/view/copy-folder-w-user-permission-intact-10274759) but I don't want to use it because of its global system impact.

How can I use windows API to move a folder cross disks without permission change? What did I miss here?

Thanks
Leon

Answer (score 1):

You can use BackupRead and BackupWrite to move directories across volumes with NTFS security intact.

BackupRead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362509(VS.85).aspx

BackupWrite: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362511(VS.85).aspx

You will need to create the folder at the destination first, then open both folders using CreateFile in order to get handles to them.

Your process will need to obtain the Backup and Restore privileges and you need to pass FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS into CreateFile.