# Recursive MoveFile/CopyFile

Tags: winapi, recursion, console-application, file-copying, movefileex

I’m working on a console program and need to use `MoveFile`/`CopyFile` to allow moving and copying files and directories (possibly across volumes). The problem of course is that copying or moving a directory to another volume does not work with the aforementioned functions because they are not recursive.

`SHFileOperation` will not do because this is a console app and I am using the variations that allow for progress display (`MoveFileWithProgress`/`CopyFileEx`), and `SHFileOperation` uses the GUI for displaying progress instead of the console.

I considered using `FindNextFile`, but even then I could not find any examples of code to recursively `(Move|Copy)File` with `FindNextFile` or otherwise—which is kind of baffling since this issue *must* have come up before.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to resort to reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't recursive? MSDN clearly states that you may give a path of a directory, and that `The MoveFile function will move (rename) either a file or a directory (including its children)`. Note however this disclaimer: `If a file is moved across volumes, MoveFile does not move the security descriptor with the file` (also in MSDN).

Comment: @Eran, it specifically says *the [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx) function will fail on directory moves when the destination is on a different volume.*

Comment: of course, I misread it... I googled it a bit, and it seems that people say that moving doesn't work, but copying & deleting does, but I didn't find actual explanations of how to copy. Seems you should just write a recursive function yourself (or take one from the web - plenty of those around). Another way (not as good, IMO, but it's still possible) is to read and write the whole folder, somewhat like what's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520481/move-folder-cross-disks-without-security-descriptor-change

Comment: @Eran, writing a recursive function is possible but annoying since it has to use FindNextFile and such and seems “kludgy”. I’m not opposed to it (maybe I can add more flexibility that way), but I just figured that there must surely be some easier, built-in way to do such an obvious, and relatively common task instead of just reinventing th wheel, which is a real anathema in the programming world.